# Running code on Page Editor load in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I need to run code on load of Page Editor. What I want to do is check the current version that is being loaded and if it's not the latest version, make it not editable. I've looked at various http piplines, but it's not clear how I get the current page being loaded.

What's the best why to go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `getPageEditorValidators` or `getPageEditorNotifications` suffice?

The `GetPageEditorValidatorArgs` from the `Process` method contains an `Item` property.

Comment: Thanks. getPageEditorNotifications is definitely the event I'm looking for to run code on load of page editor. Any thoughts on how I make the page not editable? I was thinking of redirecting the page, however, the request context is actually just the ribbon frame, not the entire page. Also I'd like to present a message to the user, any thoughts on how to do that with this event?

Comment: Do note this is a pipeline that exists on 7.2 (not 8, apparently). You could probably stack an additional `PageEditorNotification` on the `GetPageEditorNotificationsArgs` and then possibly set the `ContextItem` to some general error page. Educated guess, haven't tested it yet.